# how to response click event when screen off

Tags: android

i have a app,if my app screen off some times,i want to click the screen to  awake the screen on.i know i can press the power to deal with using flag_user_present to receive the broadcast or

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
    //do nothing but show a warning message
    Toast.makeText(this, "you pressed the power button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}

  return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

but i want to click the screen to do the same thing ,so i overload the ontouch event,but when screen off,the ontouch not receive focus and deal with the click event.
so my  question  how to deal with click event when screen off(my screen not lock and stay the same activity,only screen off)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do this when the device shuts off the screen. If the screen is off, then the touchscreen usually get's shut down immediately by the kernel (if it's not modified otherwise). This happens for obvious reasons.
You could use what tsp said in his answer, and emulate the screen off by turning it black, turn the brightness as far low as possible and then still listen for touch events. Keep in mind though, that this behavior is unexpected by the user and he might think the screen is off, where it isn't. I don't recommend doing this! Also, not all devices allow a zero brightness.

Answer (score 0):

u can use

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```